# How to edit Build system paths in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, msbuild

I want to change the build system path for building my VC++ project in VS2005.

When I  try to build the project, I'm getting an error that a specified header file cannot be opened. I have that header file in `"Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include"`.

But the path present in 'Build system path' is `"Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include"` which i found in the Error dialog box when i tried to open that header file through the code.

So I want to change the path in build system path to `"Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include"`.

How can i do this.? How to open Build system paths in VS2005.?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add include directives rather than change the build system path. Right click the project in Solution Explorer | properties

C/C++ | General

Select 'Additional include directives'

Here browse to the location of where you include files are.